# Mismatch for Ordering[list,1] and Position[list, Min[list]]

Tags: sorting

I am using Ordering[list, 1] to get the position of the minimum of a list, but in this example

```
n = 10;
list = Table[1/(k Sqrt[(n - k)]), {k, 1, n - 1}];
list // N
Ordering[list, 1] (* {6} *)
Position[list, Min[list]][[1]] (* {7} *)
```

I get a wrong answer, {6} and not {7}. Can you confirm this? What is the reason?
The same happens for 4<=n<=10. I am using version 12.0

Comment: try `Ordering[list, 1, Less]`?

Comment: ... or `Ordering[list, 1, NumericalOrder]`?

Comment: `Ordering` uses `Sort`, sorting is done using canonical ordering. Compare `N[Sort[list]]` and `Sort[N[list]]`

Comment: So the canonical ordering compares the internal MM representation of the number, while Numerical Order is the order after applying N[], is that correct?

Comment: Canonical order is for sorting WM expressions, see e.g. `FullForm[Sort[list]]`, elements are not numbers. If you want to treat elements as numbers, you should specify it explicitly as in @kglr comments.